# Run random effects model in python 3.7.2 from excel file data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, regression

I'm trying to undertake a regression using random effects with data I pulled togehter via excel.

Below is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xl = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\Documents\Studium\PythonDataSet_6.xlsx")
dx1 = xl.parse('PythonData')

reg1 = sm.OLS(endog=dx1['UE'], exogen=dx1['Return'])
type(reg1)`
```

The regression part is the one which fails and gives me the following error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-5a9bf21b4b87> in <module>
----> 1 reg1 = sm.OLS(endog=dx1['UE'], exogen=dx1['Return'])
      2 type(reg1)

 c:\users\python37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py 
in __init__(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    815                  **kwargs):
    816         super(OLS, self).__init__(endog, exog, missing=missing,    
--> 817                                   hasconst=hasconst, **kwargs)
    818         if "weights" in self._init_keys:
    819             self._init_keys.remove("weights")

c:\users\python37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py 
in __init__(self, endog, exog, weights, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    661             weights = weights.squeeze()
    662         super(WLS, self).__init__(endog, exog, missing=missing,
--> 663                                   weights=weights, hasconst=hasconst, 
**kwargs)
    664         nobs = self.exog.shape[0]
    665         weights = self.weights

c:\users\python37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
    177     """
    178     def __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs):
--> 179         super(RegressionModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)
    180         self._data_attr.extend(['pinv_wexog', 'wendog', 'wexog', 'weights'])
    181 

c:\users\python37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
    211     def __init__(self, endog, exog=None, **kwargs):
    212         super(LikelihoodModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)
--> 213         self.initialize()
    214 
    215     def initialize(self):

c:\users\python37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in initialize(self)
    184         self.wendog = self.whiten(self.endog)
    185         # overwrite nobs from class Model:
--> 186         self.nobs = float(self.wexog.shape[0])
    187 
    188         self._df_model = None

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

The excel file which I am using looks like below:

[image]

I hope these are all the information needed for an advice, where my problem could be, otherwise I'll be glad to upload more!

[Extended File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYwIs.png)

Comment: Excuse me, I don't see a "Return" column in your sheet

Comment: Return column is at the very end of the sheet, above is just a small snippet, I fix that right away, see for the link

Comment: Please show us your Excel file in text form, not as a graphic, so we can try your code and data for ourselves.

Comment: https://github.com/GonkoPilo/RegressionData

Comment: Thank you for your remark! Above you can get the file, it contains numerous variables for different firms (RIC) over different years. (It does appear I (yet) cannot directly upload files here, there github)

Comment: argument name should be exog, not exogen, https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html

Comment: Thank you so much! That is a stupid mistake, but I'm more than glad you found it, stranger on the internet, you helped me really, very much!